# SQL Query to show number of employees on leave

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX 20.1. On my dashboard, I want to show the number of employees on leave on current sysdate. I have a leave_details table with emp_id column, leave_start_date column, leave_end_date column, leave_status column. I have tried this SQL Query:

```
select nvl(count(emp_id),0)
from leave_details
where to_char(leave_start_date,'dd-mon-rr') = to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-rr')
and leave_status = 'Granted'
```

but it will only show when the sysdate matches with leave_start_date. I want to show it on the dashboard for the days between leave_start_date and leave_end_date. How can I achieve this? [This is what my dashboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvy5z.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the dates are stored as *dates* and not as strings.  So treat them as such!

For the number on leave today:

```
select count(*)
from leave_details ld
where leave_start_date <= trunc(sysdate) and
      leave_end_date >= trunc(sysdate) and
      leave_status = 'Granted';
```

`COUNT()` never returns a `NULL` value so there is no need for additional logic to check for that.

It is unclear whether or not the end of the leave is included into the leave period.  The above assumes that it is.

Note:  If you have indeterminate leaves where the end date is not known, then you can tweak this as:

```
select count(*)
from leave_details ld
where leave_start_date <= trunc(sysdate) and
      (leave_end_date >= trunc(sysdate) or leave_end_date is null) and
      leave_status = 'Granted'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
select count(1)
from leave_details ld
where leave_start_date <= trunc(sysdate) and
      leave_end_date >= trunc(sysdate) and
      leave_status = 'Granted';
```